# Trait associated type lifetime and self

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a struct that wraps a `std::cell::Ref` and provides access by reference to the underlying value. Something like this:

```rust
use std::cell::Ref;

struct IntAccess<'a> {
    i: Ref<'a, i32>,
}

impl IntAccess<'_> {
    fn get(&self) -> &i32 {
        &self.i
    }
}
```

This works fine. Since I have multiple structs like this, I'd like to define a common trait:

```rust
trait Access {
    type Item;
    fn get(&self) -> Self::Item;
}
```

However, I get into trouble when trying to implement `Access` for `IntAccess`:

```rust
impl<'a> Access for IntAccess<'a> {
    type Item = &'a i32;

    fn get(&self) -> Self::Item {
        &self.i
    }
}
```

It fails with the following error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:23:9
   |
23 |         &self.i
   |         ^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime defined here...
  --> src/main.rs:22:12
   |
22 |     fn get(&self) -> Self::Item {
   |            ^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:23:9
   |
23 |         &self.i
   |         ^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
  --> src/main.rs:19:6
   |
19 | impl<'a> Access for IntAccess<'a> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/main.rs:22:33
   |
22 |       fn get(&self) -> Self::Item {
   |  _________________________________^
23 | |         &self.i
24 | |     }
   | |_____^
   = note: expected `<IntAccess<'a> as Access>`
              found `<IntAccess<'_> as Access>`
```

I think I kind of get what the compiler is trying to tell me: I'm trying to borrow `self.i` which has an anonymous lifetime unrelated to the lifetime of `Self::Item` (`'a`). So what seems to be needed is to somehow tie the lifetime of `self` in `get` to the lifetime `'a`. Is there a way to do this?

I have to admit that I don't *fully* grasp the problem. Since I pass the lifetime `'a` to the `Ref`, and `Ref` internally stores a reference with this lifetime, it seems to me that it should somehow be possible to get a reference with lifetime `'a` out of it without having to explicitly tie `self` to this lifetime as well. So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. About your doubt, let's name the lifetimes for easier debugging:

```rust
impl<'a> Access for IntAccess<'a> {
    type Item = &'a i32;

    fn get<'b>(&'b self) -> Self::Item {
        &self.i
    }
}
```

`self` has the type `&'b IntAccess<'a>`. `'b` is shorter than or equal to `'a` - that is required for `self` to be *well-formed*, i.e. able to exist (otherwise, it would contain a dangling reference).

For that reason, we cannot borrow `self` for more than `'b` - or we could do something like:

```rust
let v: IntAccess<'a>;
let inner: &'a i32 = {
    let r: &'b IntAccess<'a> = &v;
    <IntAccess<'a> as Access>::get(r)
}
let mut_r: &mut IntAccess<'a> = &mut v;
```

And we have both a shared and a mutable reference to (parts of) `inner`!

Your problem cannot be solved fully without [Generic Associated Types](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1598-generic_associated_types.html). They allow you to parameterize an associated type by a lifetime, making it able to express "I want to return this associated type tied to the lifetime of `self`":

```rust
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]

trait Access {
    type Item<'a>
    where
        Self: 'a;
    fn get<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::Item<'a>;
    // Or, with lifetime elision:
    // fn get(&self) -> Self::Item<'_>;
}

impl<'a> Access for IntAccess<'a> {
    type Item<'b> = &'b i32
    where
        'a: 'b;

    fn get<'b>(&'b self) -> Self::Item<'b> {
        &self.i
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=97cf4690c2d12691ebc1ad6fdbc4e5e3).

Can we do that on stable? We can emulate that. Instead of implementing `Access` for `IntAccess` itself, we will implement it for *a reference to it*!

```rust
trait Access {
    type Item;
    fn get(self) -> Self::Item;
}

impl<'a, 'b> Access for &'b IntAccess<'a> {
    type Item = &'b i32;
    fn get(self) -> &'b i32 {
        &self.i
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0c7ae792290113d9c6dc751126bd193e)

This does not always work, and thus is not a full replacement to GATs, but is good enough in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation, and nice trick with implementing the trait on references! I found another approach by giving `Access` a lifetime parameter `'s` and changing `get` to `fn get(&'s self) -> Self::Item`. When implementing `Access` on `IntAccess` I then set `type Item = &'s i32`. Is this equivalent to your approach or are there subtle differences?

Comment: @mtvec That works too, and may be better depending on your use case. I just forgot about that trick. I'm not sure whether there are differences, though likely not.